# How to use Spring Boot CRUD API to insert data in multiple tables using one POST endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can a data be inserted using single POST endpoint in multiple tables. For example there are two tables

```
1. Employee
2. Department
```

[image]

These two tables have a primary key and foreign key relationship.

How to achieve data insertion in two tables using a single POST endpoint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see what you want.... your entities have to look like this...

You have to create a one to one relationship something like this:

Department entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class Department {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String description;
}
```

Employee entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Department department;
}
```

And than you can add Data on Startup like this:

```
@Component
public class DBSeeder implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Department dep1 = new Department();
        dep1.setName("Demolition");
        dep1.setDescription("Do demo");

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setName("John Rambo");
        emp1.setEmail("john.rambo@demolition.com");
        emp1.setAddress("Demolition Av. 5");
        emp1.setDepartment(dep1);

        this.repository.save(emp1);


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
  Employee save(Employee employee);
}
```

Do you also ask how the entity objects have to look like?

Comment: Will this save data in both DB tables ?

Comment: yes, the relationship is defined in your entity.